# Convert Markdown to pure Text

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I would like to manually check (with winmerge) an automatically generated markdown file against the original text source file. Just to make sure that nothing was cut off or forgotten.

I don't need any type of style information. So every markdown tags must be stripped off.

I tried to convert md to txt with pandoc only to discover that the tags remain.

How can I just get the pure text from the md file?

Answer (score 7):

```
pandoc -f markdown -t plain --wrap=none file.md -o file.txt
```

Comment: `--no-wrap` is deprecated. `--wrap=none` is now the correct command line arg.